# Rhyme Time (all the answers will be rhyming words)

Tags: word, rhyme

1:Piranha:                   _________ _________

2:Fertilizer:                        _________ _________

3:Gherkin that dates lots
of other gherkins   :            _________ _________

4:Simple eye surgery:                _________ _________

5:Dom Perignon Rose 2004:            _________ _________

6:Eating fried bananas:      _________ _________

7:Can't pay for my lodgings:         _________ _________

8:E. coli Bacteria in the food trough:       _________ _________

9:The Indian food may have made me sick! _________ _________

Spoiler:

> @Rand al'Thor, All are correct except "Eating Fried Bananas." I was going for "Bunch Munch"

Comment: Don't you mean *piranhas*, as in, plural? The rhyme for that one's very old (but curiously, not yet included in any of the answers as of writing!)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: like many other animals, *piranha* can be plural as well as singular in English without needing an *s* added.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: well, it's more that many animal names have the plural identical to the singular, but I'll grant you that piranhas *can* be referred to as *piranha*, collectively. (Rand has since added the rhyme I was thinking of to his answer.)

Comment: fish and fishes.

Comment: I am familiar with such phrases as "hink pinks" from a series of childrens books. It also helps with finding intended solutions by indicating the number of syllables, as they can be labeled "hink pink", "hinky pinky", "hinkety pinkety" and so on.

Comment: 1: 2 syllables
2: 1
3: 2
4: 2
5: 1
6:1
7:1
8: 2
9: 2

Comment: Bananas are grown in what denomination?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Piranha:

> **Vicious fishes**

Gherkin that dates lots of other gherkins :

> **Fickle pickle** (thanks [@JonMarkPerry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52445/5373))

Dom Perignon Rose 2004:

> **Fine wine** (I assume it's fine, since it seems to be pretty expensive)

Eating fried bananas:

> **Devouring [pisang goreng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisang_goreng)** (rhymes at least in some accents)

Can't pay for my lodgings:

> **Rent spent** (thanks [@Marius](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52446/5373))

E. coli Bacteria in the food trough:

> **Danger manger**

The Indian food may have made me sick!

> **Curry worry** (thanks [@PaulEvans](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52448/5373)). Not the intended answer, but hilarious, is @kaine's **vindaloo in the loo**.

Comment: how about curry worry?

Comment: @tmpearce I already posted that 2 minutes before your comment :)

Comment: try [Delhi Belly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delhi_Belly)

Comment: vindaloo in the loo

Comment: really think the "may have" points directly to "worry" :)

Comment: @kaine You win the prize for most awesome unintended solution.

Comment: Everything right (it was the currios one) except the bananas.

Comment: @PaulEvans Fixed.

Comment: Everyone knows how spicy the Indian curry is  :D

Answer (score 13):

The Indian food may have made me sick!

> blurry curry.

Can't pay for my lodgings

> rent spent

Fertilizer

> grit shit ([grit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grit) as in firmness of mind or spirit)

Simple eye surgery:

> Vision incision

Gherkin that dates lots of other gherkins

> Cucumber slumber

E. coli Bacteria in the food trough

> Infection digestion

Piranha

> Water biter

Dom Perignon Rose 2004:

> The answer Fine Wine was already given so...
>  Leap Sip as in take a Sip in a leap year. I know I know... it's forced.

Comment: lodgings is the only one that I intended, though there are a few good guesses there...

Comment: You realize that the question is very broad. When you ask people for rhymes you cannot expect to get  the same answers you thought about. But I'm glad I got one that you had in mind.

Comment: "Infection digestion", "water biter", and "leap sip" don't really rhyme or make sense.

Answer (score 8):

Gherkin that dates lots of other gherkins

> Fickle Pickle

Answer (score 8):

I have an alternative answer for just one of them:

Dom Perignon Rose 2004:

> Pink Drink

Answer (score 6):

Piranha:

> Killer Swimmer

Simple eye surgery:

> Basic Lasik

Fertiliser:

> Decomposed compost?

Comment: Nice ones, but they don't actually fit with the definition of a rhyme: "correspondence of sound between words or the endings of words, especially when these are used at the ends of lines of poetry."

Comment: *real* rhymes. As a songwriter, I get admonished by those who contend that my rhymes are not adequate.

Comment: Good job on the eye one

Comment: @Chowzen: Was "basic Lasik" right? How about "matter-of-fact cataract"?

Comment: Basic Lasik. I'm starting to get concerned about the bananas, though.

Answer (score 6):

Piranha:

> dipper ripper or splasher gnasher

Fertiliser:

> flower power

Simple eye surgery:

> gaze laze or gazer laser

The Indian food may have made me sick!

> curry worry

Answer (score 5):

Most of the others were answered already, but my idea for # 2:

Fertilizer:

> Moo Poo

Comment: funny. I actually laughed when I read this.

Answer (score 3):

Piranha:

> Vicious Fishes? (bit of a half rhyme)

Gherkin that dates lots of other gherkins

> Fickle pickle

Dom Perignon Rose 2004

> Pink drink

Can't pay for my lodgings

> Spent rent

E. coli Bacteria in the food trough

> Manger danger

The Indian food may have made me sick!

> Delhi belly

Answer (score 3):

I think I finally had an epiphany...

Eating fried bananas

> Bunch Lunch

Answer (score 0):

Dom Perignon Rose 2004

> Vintage Beverage

Can't pay for my lodgings

> No cash to crash

Piranha

> Biting herring

Eating fried bananas

> Banana pan-a (not so close but I find it funny)

Fertilizer

> Manure Culture

Answer (score 0):

1:Piranha:

> Cruel School

2:Fertilizer:

> Mature Manure

3:Gherkin that dates lots of other gherkins:

> Fickle Pickle

4:Simple eye surgery:

> Bye, eye! Lol

5:Dom Perignon Rose 2004:

> Upscale Ale or Fine Wine

6:Eating fried bananas:

> Munch bunch?  It's a stretch, but the hint in the comments said "Bananas are grown in what denomination?"

7:Can't pay for my lodgings:

> Spent Rent

8:E. coli Bacteria in the food trough:

> Barnyard Hazard?  It's a stretch

9:The Indian food may have made me sick!

> Curry Worry

Answer (score 0):

Eating fried bananas might just be

> **Crunches bunches**    — (verb tense doesn't match, but other alternatives seem worse)

Answer (score -1):

Pirana:

> River Killer

Fertiliser:

> Grants Plants

The Indian food may have made me sick!:

> Indian Digestion

Comment: Except for the middle one, these don't rhyme.